# Nested, dependant for loops: Summation formula and Big-O notation

Tags: big-o

Working under a time crunch here.  Struggling to understand exactly what this problem is asking. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advanced.
The original problem is based on this given information:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 2*n; k++) {
    cout << k << endl;  
    for (int i = k+1; i < n; i++) 
        { 
            m[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
            cout << m[i][j] << endl; 
        } 
    cout << i * k << endl;
}
```

For T(n) = http://www4c.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP63941h503ff0a609230100002eieg6bhfe5gi70g?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=23&w=167.&h=49.

And here is my problem:

1. Modify the code above to find the number of times the basic operation occurs (i.e. how many times does it go in the inner for loop?).

## include

using namespace std;

```
int main()  
{ 
    int count = 0;  
    int n = 10; 
    for (int k = 0; k < 2*n; k++) { 
        cout << "outer: " << k << endl; 
        for (int i = k+1; i < n; i++) { 
            cout << "\tinner: " << i << endl; 
            count++;  
        }  
    }  
    cout << count << endl; 
}
```

2. Write a summation based on the output of Step 1
3. Based on this, is T(n) equivalent to O(n) or O(n^2)

I'm confused about specifically what part 2 is asking for. But I found:

http://www4c.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP4561hgb5f47a07e05g00000112a53ahh0670che?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=30&w=109.&h=49.

To me this looks like O(N^2)?

I apologize for the formatting. I'm on mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me see if I guide: 
1. I think the count should be inside like this:

```
 int main()   { 
     int count = -1;  
     int n = 10; 
     for (int k = 0; k < 2*n; k++) { 
         count = 0;
         cout << "outer: " << k << endl; 
         for (int i = k+1; i < n; i++) { 
             cout << "\tinner: " << i << endl; 
             count++;  
         }  
         cout << count << endl; //<<<here 
     }  
 }
```

2. Now collect the output (@here marker) and form a formula for the summation. I think this is Task#2.
3. Based on your formula (or summation) you will be able to generalize whether its o(n) or o(n^2).

This is definitely not linear.

[image]